# “A glass of water” vs “a glass with water”

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have a question on the usage of preposition.
Is there any difference between “a glass of water” and “a glass with water”?

Comment: The first is idiomatic English, the second is not.

Comment: Would it be correct if I say “a glass with water in it”?

Comment: Yes, it would (although 'a glass/cup of' is usual when referring to a drink).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the context.

If you are in a restaurant, you order a glass of water:

> I would like a glass of water, please.

However, if you are pouring water into a glass, you fill it with water:

> Fill a glass with water, add a pinch of salt and squeeze juice from one lemon into the glass.